# Sending python dictionary to java using RabbitMQ

Tags: java, python, dictionary, rabbitmq

I try to send a  python dictionary from python to java application using RabbitMQ.
On the python side I convert the dictionary to a string using several ways.

- `str(dict)`
- `json.dumps(dict)`
- `pickle.dumps(dict)`

The result looks like:

```
{"vlan": {"ip": "12.12.12.12", "netmask": "255.255.255.255", "number": 12}}
```

I send the Message using pika and it arrives to the java "listener".
On the java side,when I convert the data into string I get:

```
QueueingConsumer.Delivery delivery = consumer.nextDelivery();
String data =  new String(delivery.getBody())
```

```
dp0
S'vlan'
p1
(dp2
S'ip'
p3
S'12.12.12.12'
p4
sS'netmask'
p5
S'255.255.255.255'
p6
sS'number'
p7
I12
ss.
```

I would like to get on the java side the same string I have sent on the python side.

Any ideas?

Comment: The output you show is the Python Pickle format, which was never designed for cross-language communication. What happened when you used JSON?

Answer (score 3):

Use a serialization format that can be written and read on *both* sides across languages.
Python pickles are obviously a native Python format that you can not deserialize in Java (except using Jython). Use JSON or XML or Protocol Buffers instead.

Comment: Update: My mistake - it works fine with 'json.dumps' and I am able to create a POJO from the incoming string using Jackson.